# Setting Up a Subdomain with Godaddy and BigBlackBag

Tags: subdomain, godaddy

OK, so I am taking over the site for my dad's small business, and whoever helped him with it before used BigBlackBag.com to build the site.  I basically want to get rid of it and start fresh, but I don't really understand how it works.

He has a GoDaddy account connected to the BigBlackBag mess as well, but I don't see how, and both sites have terrible customer service and documentation.

The thing that made me really want to get rid of it was that I was trying to set up a simple subdomain through godaddy for the site and no matter what I did it wouldn't work and I got a "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)" error message. I have a separate account with godaddy and setting up a subdomain is super easy and works fine, so I'm thinking it could be a problem with BigBlackBag.

Has anyone ever had this problem, or have any ideas how I can fix it? Could it be anything but a quirk with the service? I guess it might come down to just dropping BigBlackBag...? Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 3):

I work for [BigBlackBag](http://www.bigblackbag.com) and I'd be happy to help.
9 times out of 10 when a customer signs on to our service, we have them point their domain's DNS nameservers to us. This means that we control their domain from that point on. We do this to make it simple for our customers as most people do not understand the difference between nameservers, A records, CNames, etc. You may confirm this by checking the nameserver settings within your goDaddy account. If they are ns1.righthookmedia.net and ns2.righthookmedia.net, then we are controlling the domain's DNS and any other changes you make will not have any effect. If this is the case, then we will be happy to create a subdomain for you. You will just need to email support[at]bigblackbag.com with the following information:

1. The name of the subdomain
2. What ip or URL it points to

If you have any other questions please be sure to contact us or check our [knowledge base](http://support.bigblackbag.com).

I certainly hope you'll reconsider leaving our service. If you can follow up with your father's domain name, I will be happy to review your previous support requests. We do strive for 100% customer satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [knowledge base article](http://support.bigblackbag.com/KB/a39/how-do-i-point-my-domain-name-to-bigblackbag.aspx) on connecting a BBG account to a custom domain. It's a fairly standard process. It's also why creating a new sub-domain isn't working. You need to undo that(many registrars just provide a "reset to defaults" button for this) and replace the nameserver information with whatever DNS info your new host supplies.